# 403 User Rate Limit Exceeded and 401 Invalid Credentials - Google Analytics API v3

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-oauth

We were able get the data from Google Analytics using Oauth2.0, but now suddenly we are getting 403 User Rate Limit Exceeded and 401 Invalid Credentials.

On server start up we are getting,

> SEVERE: unable to refresh token
> com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 403 User Rate Limit Exceeded

and for subsequent requests it is giving,

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
> {
>   "code" : 401,
>   "errors" : [ {
>     "domain" : "global",
>     "location" : "Authorization",
>     "locationType" : "header",
>     "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
>     "reason" : "authError"
>   } ],
>   "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
> }

I have tested access token with following url :

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=xxxxxxxx

I am getting valid access token message, but still i am getting Invalid Credentials. I have also tried with OAuth2 playground, here also i am getting same message.

Any help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are caching the access tokens and that you are making a reasonable number of refresh requests. Refreshing in a tight loop (or too frequently from multiple threads or servers in a cluster) for the same user will lead to 403.

The 401 error is most likely due to the fact that getting a new access token failed and you are using an expired one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Here I am getting new access token using refresh token and i am giving request with new access token only. But still its not working. It was working fine, but suddenly this issue came.

Comment: What happens? How is it not working? Is the refresh token still valid?

Comment: Hi mariuss, Refresh token and access token both are valid. I am also getting same issue with https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/. It was working fine, suddenly from few days i am getting this issue.

Comment: As I mentioned, your code is probably refreshing too often. Once it gets into that state oauthplayground will behave exactly the same. Eventually it will start working again. The rate limit is based on the user that approved the refresh token.

Comment: Then whats the possible solution to avoid this ? 
We should cache the new token obtained after refresh and use it till it expires right ??